# checking savedInstanceState state in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-savedstate

Why don't we check `savedInstanceState` in `onCreateView` callback of fragment instead of `onActivityCreated`(Recommended)?
According to life cycle of fragment `onActivityCreated` called after the `onCreateView` callback in fragment lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go through this article it is clearly explained that you can call `onSaveInstanceState` anytime before `onDestroy`. So to answer your question, you can call that method in `onCreateView` method also.

[Google Developer Link - Fragment onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))